# How can I build a Boost Build target from outside my Jamroot directory?

Tags: boost-build, bjam

Make has a command line option `-C` that allows you to run make *as if* you were building from a particular directory. This option is important if you want to avoid `cd`'ing all over your filesystem from a script.

How can I accomplish the same thing with Boost Build?

Comment: Why the directory from which the build is invoked is important in your case? I can make different suggestions depending on how it would affect the build.

Comment: I guess it's been a while, but if I remember correctly, I just wanted to avoid having to use something like `(cd some-folder && b2)`. It's not a complicated scenario at all, but I felt that the option might exist and just be unknown to me.

Comment: Well, if the paths in jamfiles are specified correctly and not dependent on the current directory, then `b2 some-folder` should work.